Solving on linear and no homogeneus ODE of the second order: $yy''+y'=x$
I can't to solve the ODE
$$yy^{\,\prime\prime}+y^{\,\prime}=x,$$
in closed or a parametric way. It is possible there is not such a solution, Just a numerical one. Homogeneous way is immediate,
$$y=const., x=\int\frac{dy}{\log y}+C.$$
Thank you so  much for helping.

Try a series solution

there is no analytical solution for this ode.

($1.$) What is your question? Is it Is there a closed from solutions?. How to find a solutions?, What is the particular solution?, How to solve the ODE?, Is it possible that the ODE only has numerical solutions? or something else? ($2.$) Can you please give us more details, such as your motivation for asking this, where the equation comes from or how you want "help"?

Where did you get that DE from?
